# In AngularJS how do I bind multiple controls together for dropdowns and text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I have done is used a pre-existing HTML template and I'm going through all the elements on it converting it to AngularJS just for learning purposes and best practices.

I have a section for a user to change their status ( Online, Away, Busy ). The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="sidebar-right-header" data-ng-controller="SidebarRightController">
    <div class="pull-right posr" dropdown>
        <a href class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fs8" data-ng-class="{
                'text-green2': userStatus.online,
                'text-red2': userStatus.busy,
                'text-orange2': userStatus.away}">
            </i> <span class="caret text-muted"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-sm" role="menu">
            <li class="menu-arrow">
                <div class="menu-arrow-up"></div>
            </li>
            <li data-ng-click="SwitchStatus('Online')"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-circle text-green2 pr5"></i> Online</a></li>
            <li data-ng-click="SwitchStatus('Busy')"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-circle text-red2 pr5"></i> Busy</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li data-ng-click="SwitchStatus('Away')"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-circle text-orange2 pr5"></i> Away</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="media mtn"> <a class="pull-left mt5" href="#"> <img class="thumbnail thumbnail-sm rounded" src="img/avatars/2.jpg" alt="..."> </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="small mt5 mbn text-cloud"><b>Current Status:</b></h5>
            <h5 class="small text-white"><b>{{statusText}}</b></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I asked another question on this that got me started, namely using the ngClass directive to handle the status. You can see it at the top of the above example. I created a function that ties into the dropdown selection, called **SwitchStatus()**. The last part in question is the **{{statusText}}** as I'm not sure how to properly bind that. I mean, I can... but my controller gets clunky and I just know that I'm doing things inefficiently.

Here's my controller:

```
function($scope) {
    var userStatuses = {
       online: true,
       busy: false,
       away: false
    };

    $scope.statusText = GetStatusText();

    function GetStatusText() {
        var text;
        switch(userStatuses) {
            case userStatuses.busy === true:
                text = "I'm busy...";
                break;
            case userStatuses.away === true:
                text = "I'm away...";
                break;
            default:
                text = "I'm online!";
        }
        return text;
    }

    $scope.SwitchStatus = function(option) {
        console.log(option);
        if ( option === 'Online' ) {
            userStatuses.online = true;
        } else if ( option === 'Busy' ) {
            userStatuses.busy = true;
            userStatuses.online = false;
            userStatuses.away = false;
        } else if ( option === 'Away' ) {
            userStatuses.online = false;
            userStatuses.busy = false;
            userStatuses.away = true;
        }
    };

   $scope.userStatus = userStatuses; // default online


}
```

Also eventually ( when I figure out what the heck I'm doing ) I want to tie advanced logic into these selections, so I want to ensure that my controller is structured in such a way that can easily handle that later.

Conclusion: Trying to get a fluent binding with the user status, both the status text and the classes that signify the green dot. you can see the Font Awesome "fa fa-circle" etc. Right now, when switching the status, the ngClass part works but the status text does not.

Hope I'm not asking a stupid question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`statusText` is only ever set once: `$scope.statusText = GetStatusText();` Nothing is updating it after that, so that is why it never changes in the UI.

There's any number of ways to get it updated, but one way is to just set it at the end of the `SwitchStatus` function.

```
$scope.SwitchStatus = function(option) {
    console.log(option);
    if ( option === 'Online' ) {
        userStatuses.online = true;
    } else if ( option === 'Busy' ) {
        userStatuses.busy = true;
        userStatuses.online = false;
        userStatuses.away = false;
    } else if ( option === 'Away' ) {
        userStatuses.online = false;
        userStatuses.busy = false;
        userStatuses.away = true;
    }
    $scope.statusText = GetStatusText();
};
```

This probably could/should be cleaned up some, but this gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you for that. This seems obvious to me as well. I guess I'm trying to understand/grasp the two-way data binding of angular. This answer is correct, however I'm excited to learn a cleaner angular way. Thank you again.